# How to create Function parameter return value, and in the function contains logic to look up adjacent element of array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, logic

how to create a function counts the number of adjacent elements and returns it. if the count of  elements is the same, it will return an earlier index element, for example:

```
$arr = array(-1,-1,-1,9,9,9,-2,7,9);
$result = adjacentElement($arr); 
echo $result //it wiill return -1
```

the count of values -2 and 9 are the same = 3,

then the function will return the value -1, because the index is earlier.

My Best code

```
<?php

function arrayCountAdjacent($array) {
    $adjacentArray = array();
    $lastValue = null;
    $i = 0;
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($lastValue === null || $lastValue != $value) {
            $i++;
            $adjacentArray[$i] = array("value" => $value, "count" => 1);

            $lastValue = $value;

        }
        else {
            $adjacentArray[$i]["count"]++;
        }
    }


    return $adjacentArray;
}

$a = array(-1,-1,-1,9,9,9,-2,7,9)//return -1;
//$b = array(-2,-2,-2,9,9,9,9,-2,7,9); //return 9
//$c = array(-2,-2,-2,9,9,-2,9,9,9,-2,9,9,9,7,9,9); //return -2
$count = arrayCountAdjacent($a);


foreach(arrayCountAdjacent($a) as $result)
{
    echo "value = " . $result['value']."\n";
}
```

the output

```
value =  -1
value =  9
value = -1
value = 7
value  = 9
```

expectation

```
 value = - 1
```

Comment: Not a clear question.. Explain clearly what you want?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please provide exact conditions (with examples) for the logic. Show us your best attempt(code), where exactly are you stuck? Read [ask]!